# Xamarin Forms Android - App won't start after changing OS time to earlier date

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I encounter a problem where my Xamarin Forms Android app won't start (blank screen) after I change the Android OS date to an earlier date. I only happens when it's not connected through the debugger.

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio and Xamarin. At the time of this post, I tested with:

- Visual Studio 2019 - 16.6.2  (Also happens in 16.5.3)
- Xamarin Forms 4.7.0.968 (Also happens in previous 4.X versions)
- Phone: Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create the sample Xamarin Forms app using the "Blank Page" template.
- Run it through the debugger first (The app works and displays the welcome message).
- Close the app.
- Set the OS date/time to manual and go back one day.
- From the phone itself (without using the debugger), run the app.

After the last step, the app won't start but will instead display a blank screen. No crash. Resetting the time to automatic date when the app is closed, the app will run correctly again. If I do the same procedure but always start the app using the debugger, everything works fine.

Does anybody knows how to resolve this issue?

Edit: Since it doesn't happen while the debugger is attached, I added logs so I can use logcat to know where it reaches. When it hangs, it doesn't even seem to reach the "Oncreate" of my MainActivity class.

Comment: Does this also happen with release builds?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, debug and release. As mentioned in the edit I just made, when it hangs, it doesn't even reach the "OnCreate" method of my "MainActivity".

Answer (score 1):

I tried your steps and reproduced the issue , it shows white screen on my side and it seems be stuck .

The problem only occurs when i set time to earlier date , it works fine if i set it later date.

I have raised the issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11128 , you could monitor the progress.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that I'm not the only one. Yesterday, I also submitted the problem through Visual Studio ([here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1084385/xamarin-forms-android-app-wont-start-after-changin.html)). Should I remove the request?

Comment: You could remain the request